# move_uploaded_file failing with no error

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions

This question has been asked similarly a few times, but those answer's didn't apply to the problem I'm have. I've checked them all.

Basically, the function move_uploaded_file is returning false every time, even though I feel like I have all my ducks in a row. There is no error, it just returns false.

I have checked the file that is being uploaded, it has no errors.

It may be a permissions problem, I tried to change the directory I'm uploading the images to using chmod(dir, 0777). If it were a permissions problem, I'm not sure if this would've fixed it. Edit - Checked iswritable(dir) of the directory and it says its writable.

I do have enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute set in my form.

This is my code:

```
    function uniqueName()
    {
    $target = dirname(__FILE__) . '/TestProject/';
    $uid = uniqid();
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $_FILES['photo']['name'] = $uid . "." . $ext;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['name'], $target . $_FILES['photo']['name']))
        echo("upload succeeded");
    else {
        echo("upload failed");
    }

    return $target . $_FILES['photo']['name'];
    }
```

Am I missing anything? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you check that file extension, otherwise people can upload their own PHP files.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your code. check your php.ini setting, maybe the files your uploading are too large. also, check if the directory exists and that PHP is redirecting the file to it.

Comment: What do you mean by php redirecting the file to the directory? I thought that was what the move_uploaded_file() did? Do I need to adjust something additional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it, the first parameter of move_uploaded_files() expects the tmp_name, not the name.

Answer (score 1):

first off, and i sometimes forget make sure your form looks like this:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

key part of this is the

```
enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and as far as uploading I use the following and it works everytime:

```
if ($_FILES["fuImg"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["fuImg"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
else
    {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fuImg"]["tmp_name"], "../img/bands/" . $_FILES["fuImg"]["name"]);
    }
```

Comment: I thought about mentioning that, I do have the enctype="multipart/form-data attribute in my form.

Comment: I realized that you have your code in a function, how are you posting to that function?  It's like any other field, you post from the form to somewhere, but what ever you are posting to, should receive those values.

Comment: $_FILES[] is a global variable, that shouldn't be the problem